# Windows explorer properties configuration 

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I've red this article from howtogeek, but it didn't explain this one which is placed in the target portion when you right click on windows explorer and click properties:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe shell:desktop\Inbox
```

And why does local disk E: shows up when I have this one:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe shell:E:\FINAL SAVE DATA
```

I don't really get the code, especially the part in shell: desktop\Inbox.
What's that supposed to mean. How do I change it so that when I click on the Windows Explorer shortcut, I get to see this location:

```
E:\FINAL SAVE DATA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to omit the shell: part since you just want a file system location and you'll need to enclose it in quotes to handle the spaces in your folder name:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe "E:\FINAL SAVE DATA"
```